# Unity - C# How to print the value of variable that its name is stored in string variable

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, variables

In unity - C# script;
I want to print the value of variable (int, float , string or any var) that its name stored in string variable:
for example:

```
int Ronaldo = 7;
int Messi = 10;
string Player = "Messi";

void PrintValueOfString(Player)
{
    // how to print the value of int Messi ??
}
```

like in PHP when i want to do this i write :

```
$Messi = 10;
$Test = "$Messi";
echo $Test ;
```

Comment: `Debug.Log(Player);`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way or use a simple "print()" instead of "Debug.Log()".

```
int Ronaldo = 7;
int Messi = 10;
string Player = "Messi";

void PrintValueOfString(Player)
{
    // how to print the value of int Messi ??
    Debug.Log($"Messi: {Messi} | Player: {Player} | Ronaldo: {Ronaldo}")
}
```

This will print the following:

```
Messi: 10 | Player: Messi | Ronaldo: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You *theoretically can* do this via Reflection and [`GetField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield) like

```
void PrintValueOfString(string player)
{
    var fieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(player, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if(fieldInfo != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(fieldInfo.GetValue(this));
    }
}
```

.... **BUT DON'T** ^^

Reflection is always quite expensive, and error prone.

---

Rather use an `enum` and a `Dictionary` like e.g.

```
public enum Players
{
    Ronaldo,
    Messi
}

public Players _player;

private Dictionary<Players, int> _playerValues = new Dictionary<Playrers, int>
{
    {Players.Ronaldo, 7},
    {Players.Messi, 10}
};

void PrintValueOfCurrentPlayer()
{
    PrintValueOfPlayer(_player);
}

void PrintValueOfPlayer(Player player)
{
    if(_playerValues.TryGetValue(player, out var value))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Player {player} has value {value}");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError($"There is no value for player {player}!");
    }
}
```

or simply a one with string

```
private Dictionary<string, int> _playerValues = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"Ronaldo", 7},
    {"Messi", 10}
};

void PrintValueOfString(string player)
{
    if(_playerValues.TryGetValue(player, out var value))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Player {player} has value {value}");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError($"There is no value for player {player}!");
    }
}
```